# nodejs sessionStore with cloudant app.use inconsistent execution

Tags: node.js, session, cloudant

I'm building a cloudant sessionStore for nodeJS and am stumped by what's going on with the app.use statement. The two following app.use statements vary only in that one has the session called wrapped in a function, however this results in very different behavior.

Example 1:

```
app.use('/login*', session( {
store: sessionStore,
secret: sessionSecret, resave: false, saveUninitialized: true,
cookie: {secure: true, maxAge:24*60*60*1000},
genid: function (req) {return uuid.v4()}
}));
```

In the first example, the sessionStore routines are called which create and store a new session ID

Example 2:

```
app.use('/login*', function () {session( {
store: sessionStore,
secret: sessionSecret, resave: false, saveUninitialized: true,
cookie: {secure: true, maxAge:24*60*60*1000},
genid: function (req) {return uuid.v4()}
})});
```

In Example 2, wrapping the session statement in a function def results in only calling the sessionStore.on('disconnect') followed by sessionStore.on('connect').

I think I'm missing something really obvious, but am stumped. Two questions:

1. Why is session() execution different when placed inside an anonymous function?
2. Is this normal and should my sessionStore.on('connect') be set up to handle this situation?

Comment: Hi! Can you clarify if this is an Express app? I think app.use() - that is your Express code, correct?

Comment: Jason, yes, I'm using express-session on  nodejs V 6.7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second example, your anonymous function calls 'session' but doesn't *return* it.

Express sessions are middleware, so the first usage is correct.

You may also be interested in a pre-built session store for Cloudant: https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-cloudant

which would make your code:

`.
.
.
var app = express();
app.use(session({
    store: cloudantStore,
    secret: 'your secret',
    cookie: {maxAge:24*60*60*1000} 
}));
app.get('login', function(req, res) {
   console.log('my session is', req.session);
   res.send({ok: true});
});`

Comment: I initially went with the (app.use(session... approach, but found that I was creating a new session  for every http call, including loading javascript files, css files, etc. This created a huge number of unecessary sessions and (also) drove up the load on my cloudant db. Because I only wanted to create a session when a user logged in, I changed my approach to app.use("/login*", session() . Have I missed something fundamental here?

Answer (score 0):

@Glynn: Thanks, you gave part of the solution. I went back to the original approach in your response, but found I was still having issues with page responses. The server kept hanging. In building the cloudant session manager, one of the required routines is sessionStore.save, which I had incorrectly specified as:

```
sessionStore.save(sid, session, callback)
```

It turns out that when express-session calls sessionStore.save(), it uses:

```
sessionStore.save(callback)
```

Fixing that resolved all issues. Thanks for your help.